# Adding UIImage to new Scroll View

Tags: swift, xcode, uiview, uiscrollview

I'm trying to create a simple app in Xcode that lets me press a button and it adds an image to a view. I originally had everything working until I decided to add a scroll view, as I wanted to create multiple buttons. My problem is, the created image follows down when scrolling. Im sure this is an easy fix. My code looks like this for each button:

```
@IBAction func btnAddColorfulLights1(_ sender: Any) {

    let image: UIImage = UIImage(named: "ColorfulLights.png")!
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
    self.view.addSubview(imageView)
    imageView.tag = 10

    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 67, y: 39, width: 240, height: 338)

}
```

I think my problem is in,

```
self.view.addSubview(imageView)
```

Where I'm adding the image to view, where I need to be adding it to the scroll view.
This is my control viewer organization/set up:

[image: Document Outline View]

Here's what it should look like:

[image: Expected output]

Here's the problem:

[image: Bad output]

I know this is probably very easy but I can't seem to find any answers to my specific problem or anything that can help me. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the `UIImageView` containing the image of your lights to the `UIView` that is the contentView of the `UIScrollView`.

An easy way to do this is to create an `@IBOutlet` for the `UIView` in your scrollView.  <kbd>control</kbd>-drag from the `View` under the `ScrollView` in the *Document Outline* to your `ViewController` code.  Give the `@IBOutlet` a name such as:

```
@IBOutlet weak var scrollViewsView: UIView!
```

Then, use it to add your adornments:

```
@IBAction func btnAddColorfulLights1(_ sender: Any) {

    let image = UIImage(named: "ColorfulLights.png")!
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
    self.scrollViewsView.addSubview(imageView)
    imageView.tag = 10

    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 67, y: 39, width: 240, height: 338)

}
```